# jq -c fails in AWS pipeline

Tags: jq

I use `cat file.json | jq -c` to print out a minified json file in the logs in an AWS pipeline step. I've tested that it works locally but in the pipeline it fails and prints out the system usage:

```
jq - commandline JSON processor [version 1.5]
Usage: jq [options] <jq filter> [file...]

...
```

Why does it fail in the pipeline but not locally?

Answer (score 1):

That's not the right question. `jq -c` (with no further argument) *should* fail. According to the very output you obtained from `jq`,  `jq` always requires at least one argument: a program.<sup>[1]</sup> That fact that it sometimes doesn't fail when no program is provided is a bug. One that appears to have been fixed in 1.6.<sup>[2]</sup>

If you simply want to reformat the JSON, you can use the trivial program `.`.

```sh
cat input.json | jq -c .
```

If the input really is a file, the following is better:

```sh
jq -c . input.json
```

---

1. Or the name of a file containing the program if `-f` is used.
2. Meaning I wasn't able to reproduce the lack of error in 1.6 after trying using Windows, Cygwin and Ubuntu builds.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to use `cat file.json | jq -c .` (note the dot that's added) in AWS.

After some experimenting, I found out that this happens only in jq 1.5 (I had jq 1.6 locally), and only when using `jq -c` instead of `jq -c .` in a detached terminal. My AWS pipeline uses jq 1.5.

I reproduced it locally by downloading jq 1.5 and running:

```
$ cat input.json | ./jq1.5 -c >output.txt &
[1] 822
jq - commandline JSON processor [version 1.5]
Usage: C:\Workspace\jq\jq1.5.exe [options] <jq filter> [file...]
```

Note that the ampersand executes it in the background which simulates a detached terminal.

What works:

```
cat input.json | ./jq1.6 -c >output.txt &
cat input.json | ./jq1.5 -c . >output.txt &
cat input.json | ./jq1.5 -c >output.txt
```

To sum up, if using jq1.5 in a detached terminal, also use the dot.